# What is a lethal dose of THC?

Tags: cardiology, neurophysiology, digestive-system, respiration, organic-chemistry

With the oil form of THC being stronger then ever. What would happen if one was to take a stomach full of THC oil?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the abstract from [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0041008X74901264), the intragastric [LD50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_lethal_dose) of $\Delta^9THC$ (tetrahydrocannabinol) in sesame oil using Fischer rats was 1270 mg/kg. Assuming rats and humans are identical (they're not), for an average-sized adult human weighing 70 kg (~155 lb.), the median lethal dose would be 88.9 grams, or about 3.1 oz.

Keep in mind that's 3.1 oz. of pure THC. That's a *lot* of weed.